# How to know the execution time per thread or user in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am executing a JMeter script for 25 users i.e threads and I wish to know much time it took for each user to perform the particular action (i.e. perform the complete usecase). My intention is to be able to give an average time so to say that if 25 actual users do this function simultaneously in the real environment then the average time it will take is that amount of time. So I wish to know whether there is a feature in JMeter may be a listener that will enable me to get this statistic.

Comment: what are you missing from View Results Tree? every request have Load time

Comment: Summary Report is first thing that comes to mind. Otherwise, please provide an example of desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) is something you're looking for. It measures cumulative time of its children so you will have both individual actions timings and the total time of all actions.

Results can be visualized using i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener

[image: JMeter Transaction Controller]

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)